# Adobe Premiere choppy playback but games run smoothly

Tags: video, graphics-card, gpu, video-editing, adobe-premiere

I have the following specs:

***CPU**: Ryzen 3 3200G*

***Mobo**: MSI A320M-A Pro*

***GPU**: ASRock RX 570*

***RAM**: 16 Gb (2x8)*

***SSD**: 240 Gb*

***HDD**: 1T*

I can play DOTA 2, Tekken 7, GTA V, Valorant, and PUBG in all ultra graphics without any problem. But why is Adobe Primiere playback so choppy? I already set the Renderer to **Mercury Playback Engine GPU Acceleration (OpenCL)** but nothing happens. Also in Task Manager CPU utilization of Premiere is about 90-100%, while GPU is very low 3-6%.

Could it be that Premiere is not utilizing GPU?

How to fix this?

Comment: What's it playing back? ProRes 4k off the HD, or a low-rez 5MB video off youtube from the SSD?

Comment: 1080p 60fps. does it matter if the file is from ssd or hdd?

Comment: It all depends on how much data it needs to read per second & how much effort that then is to convert.

Comment: The performance is choppy due to the fact your GPU does not meet the [minimum requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html#gpu-acceleration).  Time to upgrade your hardware